# Spring Batch+Boot and: [org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I made an example from http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/#quick-start

and when I try to run application I have an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: ; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
2015-04-07 11:00:15.443 ERROR 11912 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

What's wrong? project is straightforward and made exactly like on spring batch web page.

Comment: how are you trying to run it?

Comment: normally, by eclipse Run Application

Answer (score 3):

It looks like

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

on main class spoils the application (tries to initialize too much things?)
after removing this annotation, 
only @SpringBootApplication left,
everything is working.